# Playing sound in WMPLib DLL Error

Tags: c#

im currently using this DLL C:\Windows\System32\wmp.dll and my code is this

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
wmp.URL = "SoundFile.wav";
wmp.controls.play();
```

[image]

and got that error anything wrong with my code? i just copy PASTE the code that i saw while searching in code project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by the error message, the Embed Interop Types feature does not support embedding classes, just interfaces.  Very easy to fix, just remove "Class" from the identifier name.  So you use the "applicable interface instead".  Fix:

```
  var wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
  wmp.URL = "SoundFile.wav";
  wmp.controls.play();
```

And yes, this is actually legal, you *can* create an instance of an interface.  COM is different :)  This seemingly weirdo magic is implemented by the [[CoClass] attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Runtime.InteropServices.CoClassAttribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the WindowMediaPlayer interface.  It tells the C# compiler what COM class needs to be created to provide that interface.

COM is a very pure interface-based programming paradigm.  The class implementation is never exposed, it just takes a simple factory to create the instance.  CoCreateInstance() under the hood.  Talking to it is only ever done through interfaces.  Like the WindowMediaPlayer interface in your case.

Answer (score 1):

in visual studio in tool box right click on a tool and select **choose item...** , now go to COM Components tab and scroll down ,tick the windows media player and Ok.
know you can right your code ...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer med = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
    // other part of your code
}
```